# Unit test bypass for third party web service call

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I'm writing function unit tests for a REST API built with Symfony2. Part of the REST API checks HTTP basic authentication against a third party web service.

This presents a bit of a challenge when it comes to unit testing as I can't create a temporary user for the third party web service.

I could hard code credentials in, but I was thinking of an alternative approach. Would it be bad practice to hard code in some logic that shortcircuits the third party API call if the environment is `test`? Is there a better way to do something like this? I'm sure other applications face this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to :

- Isolate the authentication against the 3rd party WS in a new class
- Make a mock for that class for your tests
- Use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) so that for your unit test, you can use your mock

Comment: Excellent, not sure why this idea didn't occur to me. Thanks!